# Storing fresh peaches for a long time

Tags: storage-method, fruit, fresh, peaches

We just picked a bunch of peaches off our peach tree this morning. There is additional fruit left on the tree and we already have more than we can eat in the next few days. Is there a process I can use to store these peaches for a long time (freezing or otherwise)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Freezing**

**1) Wash and peel** the ripened peaches.
 Peel them the same way you do tomatoes - boil water, drop the peaches in for 1 minute, then drop them into ice water. The skin should just slide right off.  Slice in half and remove pits. You can leave them in halves, quarter them, or slice them. I prefer slices.
**2) Mix w/ sugar & ascorbic acid.** Dissolve 1/4 tsp ascorbic acid (available in canning section at grocery store) in 3 TB cold water; mix this along with 2/3 cup sugar into each quart of peaches.
**3) Pack into freezer containers** or baggies, leaving headspace (room for expansion during freezing). 


**Canning**

1) **Same as step one above**.
2) **Fill hot, sterilized canning jars** with fruit and hot water (or juice or syrup - syrup), leaving 1/2 inch headspace. You can make canning syrup for peaches by combining 6 1/2 cups water with 3/4 cup sugar.
3) **Put on lids and process.** You must use a pressure canner for peaches.
4) You'll want to check out [this link](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_02/peach_sliced.html) for processing times, as the time and pressure depends on your altitude and the type of canning pot you use.

Comment: What's the reason for adding ascorbic acid (when freezing)?

Comment: It helps keep them from browning. You don't have to use it, though.

Comment: @joyjit, @JustRightMenus: lemon juice will work as well (and the taste goes well with the peaches)

Answer (score 3):

Quarter or eighth, lay out on a baking sheet, freeze overnight, and bag. They will keep frozen for a year.

My mom used to make a pie crust and put a bag in the crust, fill with peaches, seal the peach bag, bag the whole thing and stuff it in the chest freezer. Then, in the depths of winter, you could whip out a peach pie in about as long as it takes to bake.

Canning is also good. They can be canned plain, or with a bit of sugar and water.

Comment: Do they need to be peeled before freezing?

Comment: Nope. If you want them peeled for the final use, the skin will probably be easier to separate after thawing.