# Storing peaches

Tags: peaches

We are considering buying a fairly large box of fresh peaches.  I want them to continue to have that fresh peach taste through the winter.  Can we lay them out on newspaper or something and keep them in the basement?  Will they spoil too quickly?  A fresh peach pie for Thanksgiving and Christmas is a dream.  If I make a pie, any kind, apple, blueberry, peach etc should I bake it fully before freezing it whole?  Then defrost it and warm before eating.  Or freeze uncooked, defrost, then bake? Cobblers?  Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I think (home-) canned peaches are actually better than fresh ones. I'd just put up some jars.

Comment: I'd slice them up and freeze them, then bring them out when you want to make a fresh pie. You could make the pie first and freeze it, but I think the results would be better using the frozen peaches and fresh crust.

Comment: They definitely won't last if you try to keep them like root vegetables; there's too much tempting sugar in there for microbes to resist, and they'll just rot. But I suggest that you check out https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/storing-fresh-peaches-for-a-long-time?rq=1 for some ideas on longer-term storage (which other comments have already suggested). Either is going to require some preparation and equipment, and neither will retain the *texture* of fresh peach, but they should work reasonably well for baking.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to freeze the sliced peaches you will need to dunk them in a combination of ascorbic acid and citric acid.  We use 2 quarts of water & 2 tsp of each  acid.  As we peel and slice the peaches we dump them into the acidulated water.  Drain and freeze in gallon freezer bags.  If you have a flat tray spread them in tray so they are more individually frozen than in a lump
2. To store the peaches we find they keep , refrigerated about 3 weeks.  You might try a product ( which I have no connection to) called "Fresh Paper"  This extends the life about 5 days in our experience.
3. The temperature of your basement will make a major difference.  Again I would try to store them in a box with the Fresh Paper product at the bottom of the box.  It will give you a bit more time to process.
4. They make great fruit leather.